# Having incomprehensible error when trying to mention an event handler in another method

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop-application

I want to move my WinForms application into the system tray on the click of a tool strip menu item, but when I try to mention the method I've written, I get an error like: `Conversion from System.EventArgs to System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs not possible`, but I don't want to convert anything, I'm just giving the method my argument e.

Declaration of methods I'm trying to use:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                Hide();
                notifyIcon.Visible = true;
            }
        }

private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            notifyIcon.Visible = false;
        }
```

(note that these two are simple event handler when resizing my form and double-clicking on the icon in the system tray)

I want to use them both like so

```
private void inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1_Resize(sender, e);
            notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(sender, e);
        }
```

but on the latter `e`, I'm getting the aforementioned error. I'm currently using VS 2019 with C#

Comment: Since you don't actually use `e` in `notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick`, I would extract the body of this method into a new helper method and call it from both `notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick` and `inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem_Click`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick` requires a `MouseEventArgs` argument; right now, `e` is an `EventArgs` parameter; whether it is *actually* a `MouseEventArgs` instance: we don't know; but: you can't pass an `EventArgs` to something that is demanding a `MouseEventArgs` value. The compiler is simply telling you that *it* can't do that for you, so: you're going to have to be more specific and tell it how to get a `MouseEventArgs` value to pass to `notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick`.

Perhaps alternatively; restructure the code a bit, i.e.

```cs
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleResize();
}
private void HandleResize()
{
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        Hide();
        notifyIcon.Visible = true;
    }
}

private void notifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HandleDoubleClick();
}
private void HandleDoubleClick()
{
    Show();
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    notifyIcon.Visible = false;
}
private void inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HandleResize();
    HandleDoubleClick();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I mean, it still doesn't work when I click the menu item, but at least the error is gone.

Comment: @KingOverTheHill have you subscribed to the actual event?

Comment: What do you mean by "subscribed"? I double clicked on the menu item in the designer and the method `inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem_Click` was created by VS and that's where I wrote it like you did in your answer.

Comment: @KingOverTheHill if you look in the generated code in the designer.cs file, there *should* be some gnerated code that does something.SomeEvent += inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem_Click or similar; that's the subscription

Comment: It says `this.inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.inTrayVerschiebenToolStripMenuItem_Click);` and in my opinion this is the right subspcription, is it not?

Comment: @KingOverTheHill yup

Comment: Yeah, but it still doesn't work,, that's the problem. Thank you nonetheless for your help and tips!